A graph G is a bipartite graph where every vertex has degree of atleast 4. Prove that K4,4 is a subgraph of G.
I know why each partition has 4 vertices but I don't know how to find the exact isomorphism. Why would there be 4 vertices which have an edge with the exact same 4 vertices on the other side? To be clear, I was asked to prove why this is not a planar graph so the only way I know to do this  is to prove that there is a subraph that is isomorphic to a subdivision of K3,3 or K5 and I asked if K4,4 was a subgraph of G or not and the TA said yes. This is a homework problem. Any hints would be appreciated

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

This doesn't appear to be true, as written.

This is actually not true. It fails miserably for random graphs. Consider a bipartite graph with $n$ vertices on each part where we're adding every possible edge independently with probability $p=n^{-3/4}$ (in fact any $p$ with $n^{-1}\ll p\ll n^{-1/2}$ works). Let $X$ be the number of $K_{4,4}$'s in this graph; then
\begin{align}\mathbb EX&=\binom n4^2p^{16}\\\\&\leq n^8p^{16}\\\\&\leq n^{-4}\end{align}
so by Markov's inequality
$$\mathbb P(X\geq 1)\leq\frac1{n^4}\implies \mathbb P(X=0)\geq 1-\frac1{n^4}$$
similarly, the expected number of edges of this graph is $pn^2=n^{5/4}$, since the numebr of edges of this graph is a binomial random variable, we know by Chernoff that
$$\mathbb P(\#\text{edges}\leq n^{5/4}/2)\leq e^{
-n^{5/4}/8}\implies \mathbb P(\#\text{edges}\geq n^{5/4}/2)\geq 1-e^{
-n^{5/4}/8}$$
therefore, for large enough $n$ we have
$$\mathbb P(X=0)+\mathbb P(\#\text{edges}\geq n^{5/4}/2)> 1$$
which implies there is some realization of this graph with no $K_{4,4}$'s and at least $n^{5/4}/2$ edges; call it $G$. Any graph with average degree $d$ has a subgraph with minimum degree at least $d/2$, so $G$ has a subgraph with minimum degree $n^{1/4}/4$ which is much bigger than $4$ for $n$ large. Obviously any subgraph of $G$ is still bipartite and has no $K_{4,4}$'s; so in particular, we've found bipartite graphs with arbitrarily large minimum degree and no $K_{4,4}$'s. This approach can actually be pushed even more than $n^{-1/2}$ probably, all the way up to $\mathbb E X=\varepsilon \mathbb E\#\text{edges}$, which gives minimum degree of order $n^{8/5}$ but I won't do that here as it's overkill (notice that this value of $p$ is over the threshold of $n^{-1/2}$).
All in all, you're TA was theatrically wrong and random graphs are always weirder than you expect, as our bounds shows actually that almost all graphs in that range of $p$ have this property of high minimum degree and no $K_{4,4}$ (you just have to ask for the minimum degree of the original random graph to be high, which you can do by a union bound and Chernoff, so that you don't even need to take subgraphs)

I wanted to also make notice of how $n$ doesn't even need to be huge. You can take $n$ to be $20$ and just write a python code and generate the edges randomly with probability $20^{-3/4}$ and you are decently likely to land in such a graph
